# Cannot parse PDF encoded symbols

Tags: python, parsing, encoding, character-encoding, pdfminer

I am trying to loop through a pdf report and grab simple "Param := Value" statements. Basically the reports are test reports written in MathCad and they use this := assignment operator. So far i have been able to use PDFminer to dump the param and value along with everything else to a txt file but all the symbols are changed to the  or U symbols. I need this to be able to read the := and use that as my locator as to say so i can parse all the settings.

```
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer

    with open('output.txt', 'a') as file:
        for page_layout in extract_pages("report.pdf"):
            for element in page_layout:
                if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
                    file.write(str(element.get_text().encode("unicode-8")))
                    print(element.get_text().encode("unicode-8"))
```

Ive also tried using the process_page route like the second below this gave me an output like below which whould be a set of key:=value pairs.

> Generator full load
> current:\n'b'ZGBASE\n'b'\xef\x80\xba\xef\x80\xbd\n'b'ZGBASE\n'b'\xef\x80\xbd\n'b'1.191
> \xce\xa9\n'b'IGen\n'b'\xef\x80\xbd\n'b'7758.14
> A\n'b'IGen\n'b'\xef\x80\xba\xef\x80\xbd\n'b'MVAG\n'b'3
> KVG\n'b'2\nKVG\nMVAG\n'b'Generator
> Grounding\n'b'Ratio:\n'b'GTR\n'b'\xef\x80\xba\xef\x80\xbd\n'b'14400V

```
output_string = StringIO()
with open('CHrpt.pdf', 'r') as in_file:
   parser = PDFParser(in_file)
   doc = PDFDocument(parser)
   rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
   device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
            interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
            for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
                 interpreter.process_page(page)
        
with open('hello.txt', 'a') as file:
   file.write(str(output_string.getvalue()), encoding="utf-8")
```

The goal is to auto parse these reports and have it update our database  of settings. Im using Anaconda3 and Python 3.8 with Pycharm 2021

Answer (score 0):

If the sequences `\xef\x80\xba\xef\x80\xbd` are, as they seem to be, the UTF-8 encoding of Unicode codepoints, then what you're seeing are two characters from the Unicode Private Use Area (PUA). It's pretty common to use PUA character codes in PDF documents; the document probably also includes embedded fonts with specific renderings for those character codes. With a close examination of the rendered PDF, you might be able to see the differences between the `:=` symbol and other uses of the `:` and `=` in the document.

PDF is not designed to be a mechanism for storing information. It's a technology intended to efficiently store the rendered image of a document, so that it can be printed or displayed on various media without affecting its appearance. Retaining the semantics of the original document has never been a design goal, and tools which attempt to extract the original information will all have their limitations.

All that said, if the analysis in my first paragraph is correct, you might be able to parse the text of the PDF by searching for the sequence `"\uf03a\uf03d"`, which seems to be the pair of Unicode characters being used.

Comment: Im not sure how to search the settings of the PDF.

Comment: @AaronDalton: When I said "settings", I was quoting your question ("I need this to be able to read the := and use that as my locator as to say so i can **parse all the settings**.") I'm not talking about the settings of the PDF. I'm suggesting that instead of searching for the ASCII characters ":=", you search for the Unicode characters in my answer. I edited the answer to remove the word, since it seems to be confusing.